# Failover Hyper-V 2012 R2 with CSVs backup

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, failovercluster

We have a VMM-managed set of Hyper-V 2012 R2 clusters.

Virtual machines are backed up with TSM, but currently there is no in-place backup for clusters themselves.

I can't find (obviously I have googled it) a decent guide on how to backup a 2012 R2 failover cluster (using CLuster Shared Volumes). There is a lot of info on how to backup the virtual machines; but, as said, that is alreaduy covered.

What I need to know is how to backup (and restore) the cluster itself having into account the cluster shared volumes and how to properly restore the cluster from that backup.

Any hints?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not?

- You can back up the individual cluster machines. That sort of includes the cluster.
- There is no mechanism I know of to back up the CSV. In fact, backuping up an exposed CSV is mentioned as a weak point in DPM. THAT SAID - there is zero need for that.
- As the CSV is only supposed to contain the virtual machines and a vm backup will take a backup of all the hard disc files attached to it. There should be nothing else on the CSV.

Given that you can back up the server machines of the cluster, and that you already cover backing up the VM's - what is left over? Nothing.

Comment: Hi @TomTom, Thanks for your answer. So to puti it short, as the VMs are already covered and the CSVs should not be backed up, what about the cluster database itself?. Let's suppose that we have a total cluster failure and we should restore it. Which would be the proper procedure?. Restoring a single node and restore the remaining ones in order?. Is there a guide I can relate to?.

Comment: Well, seriously - if you are down so much that you ahve no machine left, rebuild the cluster? The most important stuff is actually the config of the machines (I have page long code to set up the network cards correctly). The rest is a 5 minute job? But that is a different question - your question is particularly about the CSV and I fail to see what you want to backup. I keep my "central files" on a vm (files) that lives on CSV, but it is backed up as a vm.

Comment: Hi @TomTom, thanks again!. Losing all the cluster nodes is rare. Mind that hese clusters are located on the same datacenter and a complete failure is possible (not likely but possible) ...we like to be prepared even for that case. If it is as simple as restoring the 1st node (authoritative) that will fit our needs i suppose.

Comment: You ahve to try. Seriously, as long as you can reconfigure nodes (which you definitely should have atuaomted), then setting up a cluster for VM's is trivial. Then restore vm's into it.

Comment: Hi #TomTom, Of course, you were right...it is not worth the effort; the only thing we care about is network config which is a PITA. Do you mind sharing the code you use to backup the network config and set it up, or at least guding me in how do you do it?.